# how to remember a user who is login

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a sign in form with a remember me checkbox. I want to know how can i allow user to keep sign in when the browser is closed or sign out person when they close the browser. A sample code would be nice thank you.

here is my code

class HomeController extends BaseController {

```
public function getIndex()
 {    

     if(Auth::check())
         {
              return Redirect::to('profile');
         }

    return View::make('index');
```

}

```
public function postRegister()
 {        
         //gets array of the register form input values
         $value = Input::all();

         // create a new instance of the User model
         $user = new User;

         $validate = $user->userValidate($value);

         //checks if the validation for the field fails 
         if($validate->fails())
           {    
               /* $message = $validation->messages();
               return $message; */ 
              return  Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validate);

           }



                 //adds the users input to speicific field in the users table
                 $user->user_name = $value['username'];
                 $user->email = $value['email'];
                 $user->password = Hash::make($value['password']);

                 //save the inputs to the users table
                 $user->save();

                 return 'information has been stored';



    }

   public function getRegister()
      {      
              $title = 'Register';
             return View::make('register')->with('title',$title); 
      }



  public function getSignIn()
      {
                 $title = 'Signup';
                 return View::make('signup')->with('title',$title);
      }


   public function postSignIn()
     {  

          //user's information
         $credentials = array('email' => Input::get('email'),'password'=>Input::get('password'));

         //logs this user in and checked if they are registered already in 
         if(Auth::attempt($credentials,false))
           {
             return Redirect::to('profile');
           }

       return Redirect::back()->withInput();

     }
```

}

Comment: You need to understand cookies: http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Answer (score 1):

You just have to turn it on in your login method:

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password), true))
{
    // The user will now be logged in and remembered
}
else
{
   // Raise a login error
}
```

This "true" parameter is to remember your user.

Here is the Laravel Auth::attempt() method declaration:

```
public function attempt(array $credentials = array(), $remember = false, $login = true)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: well i set it to false to not remember the user and it did not work

Comment: Antonio, i set the second parameter to false and then sign into my profile page. then i closed my browser and i opened back the browser and wend to the profile route and i was still login. i dont understand what i am doing wrong.

Comment: It is supposed to work, the worse in this case would be your user being stuck in Laravel cookie/session, but you cleared them and closed your browser, so you're basically saying that there's a bug in Laravel 4?! :)

Comment: well, when i clear browser cookie and try to get to the profile it redirect me to the sign in page.I login in to my profile and close the browser but when i start my browser i was still logged in

Comment: What session driver are you using? If native delete all files from ´app/storage/sessions´.

Comment: what are those files in ´app/storage/sessions

Comment: Session data, if you delete them you loose all current sessions, but just that, nothing else, laravel will recreate as soon as you browse. Try to login, logout and before accessing your site again, delete session data.

Comment: did what u told me to do, when i was signed in i closed the browser but when i open the browser and to the profile route i was still logged in

Comment: Change session ´'driver' => 'cookie'´ and then try again, but this time deleting the cookie or all of them. Just worked for me.

Comment: i change driver to cookie, then sign out and cleared my cookies in firefox. then i signed in to my profile and then close he browser. when i reopen the brower and went the profile route i was still sign in sigh...

Comment: Looks like this is happening elsewhere. Tried it on another browser?

Comment: going to try it chrome

Answer (score 0):

You could set a cookie on the users browser (make sure you tell them if you are) to identify them. But beware that this could be modified by a malicious user.
[PHP Cookies Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)